# Gem Green Monkey - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, erb

Has anyone used  "[Green Monkey](https://github.com/Paxa/green_monkey)" to create an HTML-layout with microdata properties?

I'm struggling to understand how to go from Haml to Html.erb, according to the documentation. For example, I haven't figured out the Haml `%span[:name]= item.name`.

I get most of it except `[:name]`.

How do I translate this in html.erb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Green Monkey adds an extension to Haml. The documents display what the input and output look like.

Haml input (assuming `item.name` is set to `'Item name'`):

```
%span[:name]= item.name
```

HTML output:

```html
<span itemprop='name'>Item name</span>
```

It is taking the value in `[]`, transforming it into HTML attributes. Symbols become `itemprop` attributes, and `Mida` objects become `itemscope` and `itemtype` attributes.

There is a also a helper the documention mentions above that example, which would work like this:

```html
<span<%=mida_scope(:item)%>><%=item.name%></span>
```

`mida_scope` transforms the Mida-aware objects to HTML attributes and outputs those using the Rails `tag_builder.tag_options(html_attributes)`.

Comment: Hello @Garrett ,


Yep, that's pretty much it. Except that, the "mida_scope(:item) " helper only provide an html output for the Schema type, as it will looks like this: " itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SchemaType"' . Thus, it can't be used to create an "itemprop" for instance. I guess that for those ones I will simply have to write them, in an old fashion way.